# Unable to access the web-Page through URL without making entry in localhost file

Tags: dns, windows-server-2008, sas

We have setup a SAS EBI server in our institute to host our statistical analysis web application based on  SAS Bi server. (This application is hosted in our privately owned server)

The url to access the application is like http:\stat..res.in:8080/sasportal.

the problem is that we are not able to connect to it from machines in our institute just by typing that url in the web browser. We first need to enter the IP address and url in to the host file of the systems from which we want to access the application, then only we are able to access it.

I believe this issue has something to do with DNS.. but need some expert help to pin point the issue.

I would appreciate any help in this matter.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have correctly identified the problem. The machines cannot resolve the FQDN to the IP address, which is why they cannot connect to it.

If this is only for internal use; you have some options:

1. If your machines are managed, you can push changes to `HOSTS` and map the IP to the FQDN, and then flush the DNS cache on the systems.
2. If you have ActiveDirectory (which includes DNS), add this zone (`stats.in`) and create an `A` (*Address*) record to point to the IP. All hosts that use the DC to resolve will be able to resolve the name.
3. If you do not have ActiveDirectory; install a a local DNS fowarder/resolver. In it, add a zone that maps `stats.res.in` to the IP address of the machine. If you network is using DHCP, you can modify the DHCP server to add this local DNS server as part of the network configuration; so when when the DHCP lease expires and the clients renew the IP, they will get the new DNS information. No end configuration is required.

If you have static IPs on your network, you'll have to manually go to each machine (or update their system images and restore them) to add your local resolver as the primary DNS for their network configuration.

If the zone `res.in` is externally managed (by your ISP or web host):

1. As them to create an `A` (Address) record and point it to your company's externally provided "real" IP. You can get another "real" IP from your ISP for this service; or if you are going to use an existing IP, make sure no other service is listening on port 80 for that real IP.
2. Using your router/network management console; map requests from that "real" IP, to your internal network IP.  If you have a real IP of `5.5.5.5`, your network should be configured so that `5.5.5.5:80 --> 192.168.1.145:80` (assuming that `192.168.1.145` is the local IP of the server hosting the service).
3. No change is required on your client systems as they will automatically resolve once the DNS changes propagate.